# Return key pressed on UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` which I am using as text entry in a chat application. When the user presses return then I want to do some action e.g. save the chat message.
I haven't been able to find a solution that allows me to do this (lots for TextFields but not for TextView).
Here is the solution I am trying at the moment, which seems to be the most obvious I can find, but it isnt working, in debug I see that the method isn't touched:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        NSLog(@"Return pressed");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Other pressed");
    }
    return YES;
}
```

In my chat .h file:

```
@interface ChatTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
```

and viewdidload .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    enterText.delegate = self;
    // more
}
```

Incidentally if there is a better field to use as input in a chat program than UITextView please let me know.

Many thanks

Comment: Its working with me... I can see `Return pressed` in log..

Comment: connect delegate in IB and try again

Comment: maybe this is the issue, when I try to connect the delegate in IB, it wont, maybe because its in a cell?

Comment: Ok I got it working, thanks @Nikolai was an issue with the delegate connection

Comment: Though not sure how to close this question now.

Comment: what about using the `-textViewShouldEndEditing:` delegate method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... but it isn't working, in debug I see that the method isn't touched

Your problem obviously is that the delegate method is not called. Fix the delegate and use the code you already have: it's good.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. No need to go with delegates.

Add this event responder at where you initialize the textView.

```
[theTextView addTarget:self
                action:@selector(targetMethodToPerformCustomOperation)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
```